# How to create a div tag for every record selected in my database

Tags: php

I'm working on my results page for my website's search engine and I am trying to figure out how to create a div tag for every record selected from my database. I am using php.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: did you Google your question's title? I found a whole slew of results.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the result of $query and echo each row in a div like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM mytable");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
       echo "<div>".$row['column']."</div>";
   }
} else {
   echo "<div>No results found</div>";
}
```

Comment: couldn't be any simpler than that.